# Android: Opening a Fragment from another

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am new to Android and this is my second app. I am creating a tabbed activity where the first fragment has a form to create a new task, the second fragment has the list of all the saved tasks, and the third fragment will show the comments on a task when selected from the list in the second fragment. The third fragment is also supposed to act like a chat activity which posts comments when you type them in and tap the send button. When I implement this chat activity from a separate `Activity` (`CommentsActivity.java` in the GitHub branch in the link below), the app runs absolutely as it is supposed to. However, when I try to implement the same code from the third `Fragment`, I have the following problems:

- I have to tap the list item (in `TasksFragment.java`) twice before the `CommentsFragment` is launched.
- The fragment remains blank and shows no details or comments.
- The title bar is messed up. It does set the title correctly when `CommentsFragment` is launched for the first time. However, it becomes blank subsequently, when I swipe between the fragments . Sometimes it even shows the title of the last open fragment instead of the one currently open.

You can find all my code here: https://github.com/geekskool/android-teamwork/tree/only_fragments

Other details: I am passing the data between the `TasksFragment` and the `CommentsFragment` with fragment interaction methods that interact with the main activity--`AddTask.java`. This is the only way I know of. If there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: You can remove the logcat as its not relevant here, logcat is only needed whenever you get a crash

Comment: Removed the logcat. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your branch and noticed that you are using a `ViewPager` and trying to use `FragmentTransaction` to update the fragments inside the `ViewPager`. This does not work as the fragments will already have been created when the `ViewPagerAdapter` is created and cannot be attached to the `ViewPager` through a `FragmentTransaction`.

Here is how I solved it. Since I was using a ViewPager, using `FragmentTransaction` as below did not work:

**Wrong way:**

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
CommentsFragment commentsFragment = CommentsFragment.newInstance(mTaskId, mTaskName);
ft.replace(R.id.container, commentsFragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

With the ViewPager, I had to update the adapter populating it and then set it to the correct fragment. This is what I did:

**Right way:**

In the onListItemClick() in the TasksFragment, call this interface method onFragmentInteraction. And then in the main activity AddTask, implement it as below:

```
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(String taskId, String taskName, String assigneeRef) { 
    CommentsFragment commentsFragment = CommentsFragment.newInstance(taskId, taskName);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.fragmentList.remove(2);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.fragmentList.add(commentsFragment);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
}
```

Hope this helps you and someone else who faces a problem with updating Fragments inside a ViewPager.